# How to use dojo.query() and dojo.place() together?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to create a dynamic table which will have rows added and removed throughout its use. I do not want to have to put id's on every container that I later want to reference.

For instance, I want to add a hidden input to the last cell of a dynamically added row. The row has an id, how can I use dojo.place() when I do not have an id on the last cell?

```
var pmrCount = dojo.query("#pmhTable >tbody >tr").length;
var rowID = 'pmr_' + pmrCount;

var newPmrRow = 
    '<tr id="' + rowID + '">' +
        '<td>' + pmh + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + String(pmr.severity).charAt(0) + '</td>' + 
        '<td>' + pmr.customerName + '</td>' + 
        '<td>' + pmr.deviceType + '</td>' + 
        '<td>' + pmr.deviceModel + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + pmr.deviceSerial + '</td>' +
        '<td align="center"><a class="cancel-link"></a></td>' + 
    '</tr>';

//dojo.place(newPmrRow, dojo.query("#pmhTable >tbody"));

var newPmrHiddenInput = 
    '<input type="hidden" name="pmrs" value="'+ JSON.stringify(pmr)+ '">';

//dojo.query("#" + rowID + " td:last").place(newPmrHiddenInput);
```

The two commented lines of code are the ones that I am trying to replace with functional code. These do not work, they don't surface any warnings in the error console like other syntax errors. Not sure where to go from here.

I know that dojo.query() returns a NodeList and place() is expecting an DOM node or an id. What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at the [dojo/NodeList-dom](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/NodeList-dom.html#dojo-nodelist-dom) extension to Nodelist.  It allows you to place each element in a NodeList into an element based on query selector . In AMD Style it looks like:

```
require(['dojo/dom-construct', 'dojo/NodeList', 'dojo/NodeList-dom', 'dojo/domReady!'], function (domConstruct, NodeList) {
    var nodes = new NodeList([domConstruct.toDom('<div>someContent</div>')]);
    nodes.place('#x');

});
```

Looking at the docs I was kind of surprised there wasn't an easier way to do this, so maybe there is a better way than this.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that the place function is still expecting an id of some DOM element that I'm going to place it in. In my case, I don't have IDs on DOM element that I want to place() into.

Comment: The `'#x'` parameter can be replaced with any css selector.  From your example, it could be `"#" + rowID + "> td:last-child"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found two lines of code that seem to work, but I don't know if referencing NodeLists in an Array style is technically correct for this. This is what I did.

```
dojo.place(newPmrRow, dojo.query("#pmhTable >tbody")[0]);
dojo.place(newPmrHiddenInput, dojo.query("#" + rowID + "> td:last-child")[0]);
```